# Can generate scaffold put the controller in a namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I want to generate the scaffold in a Rails app, generating the model as usual but having the controller inside the admin namespace. Is it possible?

Answer (score 21):

The first time I've done it, I run

```
script/generate scaffold blog
```

and then refactored the controller, views, etc. My prefered solution at the moment is:

```
script/generate scaffold admin::blog
```

and then refactor the model, unit test and migration; it's less work.

If there's a better answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: admin/blog works slightly better for me, but it's only a little and quite possibly totally subjective.

Comment: in Rails >3 `rails g scaffold admin/blog`

Answer (score 8):

You can do this for rails < 3:

```
script/generate scaffold Blog title:string
```

or

```
script/generate scaffold admin::blog title:string
```

For rails > 3:

```
rails g scaffold Blog title:string
```

or

```
rails g scaffold admin/blog title:string
```

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 6:

assuming you have a model like:

```
rails g model Foo name:string
```

then you can do this with

```
rails g scaffold_controller Admin/Foo name:string --model-name="Foo"
```

(specifying the model name stops the controller from referring to the model Admin::Foo which would be the default)

NB: this isn't perfect; You'll have to fix up a bunch of path errors in your views and tests - but it gets you 80% of the way there.

Comment: `--model-name="Foo"` is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I think this is the best available at this point (Rails 7), though it still gets some route helpers wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This question is pretty widely asked on stackoverflow. And I also faced this problem and found no standard solution for that.

So, I created [rails-admin-scaffold gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-admin-scaffold) (for now it's Rails 4 only) which automates this process and wrote [an article](http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-admin-scaffold) with more detailed explanation. Hope it would be helpful for someone.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa I also encountered such issue. If there's a model called Admin, then it is impossible to have `Admin` namespace -- because rails would namespace it with a module with same name -- therefore, it would be a name conflict.